what role does mesomeric effect and inductive effect play in stability of carbocations in presence of halogens

what should be the ideal explanation behind the order of stability of these three compounds?
Case-1
In these three examples the first two structures have a positive mesomeric effect and it is greater in case of fluorine due to 2p-2p orbital overlap where as in case of chlorine it is a 3p-2p orbital overlap and in the third case there is no such effect. overlapping factor has more importance while considered in acidic strength.
and order of stability should be:
i>ii>iii
Case-2
The Inductive effect has a higher precedence over mesomeric effect in case of halogens present and since F is more electronegative than Cl the least stable structure will be the first one and then the second least stable is the second structure
and order of stability should be:
iii>ii>i
which explanation is correct and where am I going wrong?

Mesomeric effect can only be applied for a conjugated system sind this alkyl halide and alkane are not showing such configuration we'll go with inductive effect

@user145624 Maybe I have misleading phrases in my post. But you are saying a lone pair adjacent to a carbocation cannot stabilize it?

It may be called hyperconjugation as by hydrogen in structure II. Halogen have ability to do the same as in the case of bromination of alkene (e.g., bromonium ion intermediate).
